# Finding optimal nodes whose presence satisfies nested JSON logic

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, tree

Below is the JSON, I am using to generate following UI:

```
{
    "Text" : "1. Parent group"
    "Logic" : "all of the following",
    "Id":"1" //some unique id
    "children": [
        {
            "Text' : "1.1 Level Child group"
            "Logic' : "1 or more of the following",
            "Id':"1.1" //some unique id,
            "children" :  [
                {
                    "Text' : "1.1.1 Level Child group"
                    "Logic' : "all of the following",
                    "Id':"1.1.1" //some unique id,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "Text' : "1.1.1.1 Level Child"
                            "Id':"1.1.1.1" //some unique id,

                        },
                        {
                            "Text' : "1.1.1.2 Level Child"
                            "Id':"1.1.1.2" //some unique id,
                            "Logic" : "one or more of the following",
                            "children" : [
                                      { 
                                      "Text": "1.1.1.2.1 Level Child", 
                                      "Id": "1.1.1.2.1" 
                                      }, 
                                      { 
                                     "Text": "1.1.1.2.2 Level Child", 
                                      "Id": "1.1.1.2.2" 
                                      }, 
                              ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Text' : "1.1.2 Level Child group"
                    "Id':"1.1.2" //some unique id,
                },
                {
                    "Text' : "1.1.3 Level Child group"
                    "Id':"1.1.3" //some unique id,
                },
                {
                    "Text' : "1.1.4 Level Child group"
                    "Logic' : "one or more of the following",
                    "Id':"1.1.4" //some unique id,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "Text' : "1.1.4.1 Level Child"
                            "Id':"1.1.4.1" //some unique id,
                        },
                        {
                            "Text' : "1.1.4.2 Level Child"
                            "Id':"1.1.4.2" //some unique id,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Text' : "1.1.5 Level Child group"
                    "Logic' : "all of the following",
                    "Id':"1.1.5" //some unique id,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "Text' : "1.1.5.1 Level Child"
                            "Id':"1.1.5.1" //some unique id,
                        },
                        {
                            "Text' : "1.1.5.2 Level Child"
                            "Id':"1.1.5.2" //some unique id,
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "Text" : "1.2 Level Child"
            "Id":"1.2" //some unique id
        }
    ]
}
```

```
 1. Parent group (all of the following)

    1.1 Level Child group (1 or more )

        1.1.1 Level Child group (all of the following)
            1.1.1.1 Level Child // selectable
            1.1.1.2 Level Child // selectable

        1.1.2 Level Child   // selectable

        1.1.3 Level Child  // selectable

        1.1.4 Level Child group (one or more of the following)
            1.1.4.1 Level Child  // selectable
            1.1.4.2 Level Child  // selectable

        1.1.5 Level Child group (all of the following)
            1.1.5.1 Level Child  // selectable
            1.1.5.2 Level Child  // selectable

    1.2 Level Child   // selectable
```

Node working logic:

1. only nodes with no children can be selected by the user.
2. Node is implicitly selected if the Logic is "all of the following" if and only if all its nested children are selected
3. Node is implicitly selected if the logic is "n or more of the following" if only if its "n" nested children are selected

Scenario: If the user selects **1.1.2**(it implicitly satisfies **1.1**) and **1.2** then "1. parent group" is "Met", so it is selected(makes the whole group met);

Scenario: If the user selects **1.1.1.1**, the user has to select **1.1.1.2** so that **1.1.1** is "Met" and selecting **1.2**, will make the whole group as "Met".

**Actual need is to find the optimal ids when "parent group is not met":**

> If the selecting any nodes and the **top most parent group** is still not "met".
>   Then On a button click, I need to find and return the optimal node ids
>   whose presence would have made the "parent group" to be "Met".

**NOTE : when finding the optimal node ids we should importance to child groups if any of its children are selected.**

For eg:

> If only **1.2** is selected by the user, the fastest way to make the
>   "parent group" to met is to select **1.1.2**.  But if **1.1.1** has any children
>   selected, then I should give precedence to **1.1.1** node, as result I
>   need to return following ids: [
>   **1.1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1** ]

Not sure what type of algorithm, I should be using to solve this problem.

Comment: you may start by adding valid data. how do you know if a node is selected?

Comment: every time a node is selected, I maintain the node id in an array.

Comment: and how does it look like?

Comment: Let us say the user selects, "1.2 Level Child" node. All I do is store the node "Id" of the particular node. It would look like this : ["1.2"]. If you want a property to be added called "selected":true or false based on the node being selected or deselected. I can do it.

Comment: if a user select something where do you get the selected nodes from?

Comment: I use a global array which stores all the selected node ids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210387/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-praveen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a short approach by having a look to the constraints, which are now in the data set metioned with `q: 'some'` or `q: 'every'`.

```js
function select(node, selected) {

    function iter(node) {
        if (!node.children) return [node.Id];
  
        var temp = node.children.map(iter);

        if (node.q === 'every') return [...temp.flat(), node.Id];

        var filtered = temp.filter(a => a.some(v => selected.includes(v)));
        if (filtered.length) return [...filtered.flat(), node.Id];

        return [...temp.reduce((a, b) => b.length < a.length ? b : a), node.Id];
    }

    return iter(node).filter(v => !selected.includes(v));
}

var data = { q: 'every', Text: "1. Parent group", Logic: "all of the following", Id: "1", children: [{ q: 'some', Text: "1.1 Level Child group", Logic: "1 or more of the following", Id: "1.1", children: [{ q: 'every', Text: "1.1.1 Level Child group", Logic: "all of the following", Id: "1.1.1", children: [{ Text: "1.1.1.1 Level Child", Id: "1.1.1.1" }, { Text: "1.1.1.2 Level Child", Id: "1.1.1.2" }] }, { Text: "1.1.2 Level Child group", Id: "1.1.2" }, { Text: "1.1.3 Level Child group", Id: "1.1.3" }, { q: 'some', Text: "1.1.4 Level Child group", Logic: "one or more of the following", Id: "1.1.4", children: [{ Text: "1.1.4.1 Level Child", Id: "1.1.4.1" }, { Text: "1.1.4.2 Level Child", Id: "1.1.4.2" }] }, { q: 'every', Text: "1.1.5 Level Child group", Logic: "all of the following", Id: "1.1.5", children: [{ Text: "1.1.5.1 Level Child", Id: "1.1.5.1" }, { Text: "1.1.5.2 Level Child", Id: "1.1.5.1" }] }] }, { Text: "1.2 Level Child", Id: "1.2" }] };

console.log(select(data, ["1.2"]));
console.log(select(data, ["1.2", "1.1.1.1"]));
console.log(select(data, ["1.1.1.1"]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Code works almost perfectly, expect the use-case where direct child selection should be given more weight. If "1.1.1.2" has children(see the updated JSON) then running select(data , ["1.1.2","1.1.1.2.2"]) should return [1.2,1]; because "1.1" is already met because "1.1.2" is selected.

Comment: To fix it, I add this this code after `var filtered ..` `var all =  node.q === 'every', is1orMore = node.q === 'some', childMetSoFar = 0 ;
                if (node.children) {
                    node.children.forEach(function(child){
                        if (!child.children && selected.includes(child.Id)) {
                            childMetSoFar++
                        }
                    });

                    if (is1orMore == true && childMetSoFar >= 1) {return [];}
 }`. But failing for select(data , ["1.2","1.1.4.2"]) => [] but returning [1.1,1].

Comment: to the first, why is the node `"1.1"` not in the result set? should every *some* conditions nodes not included in the result set?

Comment: which scenario are you referring here?

Comment: this one `select(data , ["1.1.2","1.1.1.2.2"])`

Comment: It is because since 1.1 is "1 or more of the following" => so it required atleast one of its children to be selected. Since "1.1.2" is a directly children of "1.1" which means "1.1" is already met, we don't need it.

Comment: i need to sleep about it ;-)

Comment: Ok, Nina. But thanks a lot because at-last I have something to work with.

Comment: can you give me to the actual data some more calls and the wanted results?

Comment: Nina the actually, I can use what we have and it works almost. So, I am going to accept your answer. Thank you again for your help.